# Multiple attributes with same (identic) values - inheritable?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, entities

I am about to set up an online store and I am kinda "testing" if magento (1.7., Community Edition) fits my needs. I think I got the idea behind categorizing and attributing products. But I have a question to the attributes concerning products - or in detail: for configurable products.

**Is it possible to "inherit" attribute values (options) from another existing attribute?**

I'll give you an example to visualize my question:

Let's say we sell boxes. We would have three different types of boxes:

1. uni-color boxes ("box-color")
2. boxes with a seperate "top-color"
3. boxes with a special printing on it, which has its own color ("highlight color")

To assign colors to box type #1, I would have the possible values

- black,
- white,
- orange.

Box type #2 might come as

- black box / black top (it might seem redundant, but there is a difference to uni-colored boxes),
- black box / white top,
- black box / orange top,
- white box / black top,
- white box / white top,
- white box / orange top,
- and so on.

And finally, box type #3 might come as

- black box / black top / black highlight,
- black / white / orange,
- black / black / white,
- etc.

I think you get the idea.

I would like to have one attribute of color-options which I would maintain (like add new colors, delete old ones, etc.) - and use it as all three different types of configurable color sets.

To be able to create configurable products I would add the color-attribute to my special "boxes" attribute set(s). But when it comes to the two-colored-boxes, I am not able to add the color attribute a second time.

Is there any other (simple) way to achieve this? Since I am new to Magento I would not like to dig too deep into the code or even want to develop a module (?).

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your answers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento gives the support for what you need but it's kind of a long shot.
You are able to set a different source model to your dropdowns.
Let's take for example the attribute `tax_class_id`. It's a dropdown but it does not have the values stored in the database (tables `eav_attribute_option` and `eav_attribute_option_value`). The source model is `tax/class_source_product` that in a non-customized instance translates to class `Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product`.
In the case of `tax_class_id` the options shown in the dropdown are the result of `Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product::getAllOptions()`.
You can create a custom extension with a custom model (or 3 - one for each attribute). Set those models to be the source model for your attributes and add your logic inside the `getAllOptions()` method. In this method you can get the values from a table or hard code them, even get them through an external API.
Your custom source models should extend `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract` and should have the following methods:

- `getAllOptions()` - this is where the logic is. This should return an
  array of arrays. the array at the lower level should look like 
  `array('value'=>'SOME NUMBER HERE', 'label'=>'Label here');`
- `getOptionText()` should be similar to the one in `Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product`
- `toOptionArray()` similar to
  the one in `Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product`.
- `getFlatColums()`
  similar to the one in `Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product` just
  change the column comment
- `getFlatUpdateSelect()` similar to the
  one in `Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product`

[Check this](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html) for a small tutorial on how to add an attribute with custom options
Also follow how the source model for `tax_class_id` is made. It helps.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a solution. It is a little too much hard coding for me at the moment, since I did not really dig into coding yet. I guess for testing purposes, it would be easier to continue with three different attributes with the same options.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a single attribute for this, since the color attribtue only shows the selected value. Also the configurable products only shows the associated colors for the simple products.

Comment: Um ok. I couldn't figure out how. Because if I add the attribute containing the colors to the attribute set for the new (simple) product from which to create the configurable from, I can only choose one color. The way I figured was to create three different color attributes with identic options (values).